# trouble making in xpath for "ul" html code in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

HTML code:

```
<div id="routingPanel" class="">
<div id="routingPanelRight">
<ul id="routingList" class="ui-sortable">
<li class="ui-menu-item ui-draggable" style="display: list-item;" role="presentation" data-type="srl" data-id="15">
<a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">AS-HTTS-US-LAN-SW</a>
<span class="fa fa-trash"/>
<span class="type">[srl]</span>
</li>
<li class="ui-menu-item ui-draggable" style="display: list-item;" role="presentation" data-type="queue" data-id="119">
<a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">AS-EMEA-NORTH</a>
<span class="fa fa-trash"/>
<span class="type">[queue]</span>
</li></ul></div></div>
```

I need to click on a button which is having the span class"fa fa-trash" but it is inside li class. And i have list on buttons on the page with li class changing.

I am giving testdata from excel file so i can't use the direct value.

i tried to use this xpath

```
.//*[@id='routingList']/li[5]/span[1] //testdata1
.//*[@id='routingList']/li[2]/span[1] //testdata2
```

where li value changes everytime from excel file.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated((By.xpath("//ul[@id='routingList']/li/span[1]")))).click();

        List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id='routingList']/li/span[1]"));
        for (WebElement option : options) {
              if(testData.equals(option.getText()))
                option.click();
```

Tried above code but it is deleting only one from the list ,where i have passed two more testdata that needs to be deleted.

Need suggestions Please

Comment: Is an exception thrown or it just doesn't work ?

Comment: no exceptions , it just doesn't work for other testdata with the same keyword defined in excel file, i am using keyword driven framework.

Comment: What is testData in that statement ? `if(testData.equals(option.getText()))`

Comment: its a name. UK it is having button for deleting that selected option. For example from dropdown i am selecting some options like UK,US,India . In the corner of the UI , they ll be listed (selected options) and will have delete button for individual option. so i need to click on that delete button ,which is of trash icon. And i am sending those names from excelfile

Comment: OK, sorry to ask that much questions, but I think I have an idea of what is going on. So, does your testData look like something like that ? `AS-EMEA-NORTH` ? Or is it a part of it ? Or not at all ?

Comment: yes you are correct. that's my testdata.

Comment: Ok. I think I understand the problem. I will write an answer

Comment: Okay thank you. that will be really helpful as it is eating my whole time for coding.

Comment: AS-HTTS-US-LAN-SW [delete button][srl]
    AS-EMEA-NORTH [delete][queue]
    AS-HTTS-US-HW [delete][srl]
    AS-Emerging-RCIS [delete][queue]
    AS-EMEA-UK [delete][queue] .to be more precise, It will look like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the information you gave me in comments, I think the problem is that you are trying to get a text from an element that doesn't contain text.

Let's say your testData is `AS-HTTS-US-LAN-SW`. In the HTML you provided and the xpath you mentioned, you are selecting an autoclosing tag `<span class="fa fa-trash"/>`. Once this tag is selected, you are trying to get the text inside of it, and there is none.

```
<ul id="routingList" class="ui-sortable">
    <li class="ui-menu-item ui-draggable" style="display: list-item;" role="presentation" data-type="srl" data-id="15">
        ===========================
        <a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">AS-HTTS-US-LAN-SW</a>  ----> The text is contained here
        <span class="fa fa-trash"/> ---> No text in that tag
        ===========================
        <span class="type">[srl]</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So, basically, you have to modify a little bit your xpath from :  `//ul[@id='routingList']/li/span[1]` to : `//ul[@id='routingList']/li/a` to get the text, and then go back to the parent node to find your button with : `../span[contains(@class, 'fa fa-trash')]`

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated((By.xpath("//ul[@id='routingList']/li/span[1]")))) // removed the click here because you were clicking on the first element of the list

List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id='routingList']/li/a"));
for (WebElement option : options) {
    if(testData.equals(option.getText()))
        option.findElement(By.xpath("../span[contains(@class, 'fa fa-trash')]")).click();
```

Tell me if it helped

Comment: Thank you it worked like charm :). I think i need to work on this kind of HTML more to get exposure.  i just changed option.findElements to option.findElement as it gave me class cast Exception.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry... Little typo here. I will update the answer as well

Answer (score 1):

I know you already accepted an answer but there's a more efficient way to do this. You can specify the text you are looking for as part of the XPath. So, you do a single search instead of looping through all the options which can be a performance hit if there are many options. Also, with something like this you are likely to use it more than once so put it in a function.

In this case, the function would take in the string you are looking for and then click the appropriate element.

```
public void selectRegion(String regionName)
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[.='" + regionName + "']/following-sibling::span[@class='fa fa-trash']")).click();
}
```

and you would call it like

```
selectRegion(testData);
```

The function looks for an `A` tag that contains the desired text and then clicks the sibling `SPAN` with class `fa fa-trash`.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I didn't think out of the box and posted my answer without thinking enough. The funny part is that I almost never use a list of WebElements and always try to get what I want from a single locator. Your answer is more correct than mine

Comment: @NicolasG.Duvivier It's hard, at times, to not get swept into how the OP is coding things and just provide a quick fix. I find that many times I would do things quite differently. Sometimes I take the time to rewrite the whole thing and explain, other times I just don't have it in me at the time.

Comment: It's probably something I will learn with experience :D. Will do my best to get that as fast as I can